# How can I fix transaction error of firestore in flutter?

Tags: dart, transactions, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm implementing chat app and have to use transaction to synchronize messages of users. But, there are fatal error which terminates application abruptly. How can I deal with?

I searched many materials for this, but there was no solution. [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14655#issuecomment-440540922) is related on this and I already wrote [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27840) on this.

```
Future<void> sendMessage(String content,String receiver,String chatRoomID) async {
  DocumentReference doc = Firestore.instance
    .collection(firestoreMessageCollection)
    .document(chatRoomID)
    .collection(chatRoomID)
    .document(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());

  await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((tx) async{
    await tx.set(doc,{
      firestoreChatFromField: sl.get<CurrentUser>().uid,
      firestoreChatToField: receiver,
      firestoreChatTimestampField: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      firestoreChatContentField: content
    });
  });
}
```

I expected right result which transaction does normally, but below error is occurred and application was terminated.

> E/AndroidRuntime( 1719): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided document reference is from a different Firestore instance.

Even if I'm using same firestore instance, it is occurred continuously. Are there anyone who solved this horrible problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was related on the firestore setting. When you initialize firestore settings, jus use `Firestore.instance`. If you use other instance, it occurs my error

Comment: what did you do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue. It was fixed when I updated document reference code. Can you try changing document reference

from:

```
DocumentReference doc = Firestore.instance
    .collection(firestoreMessageCollection)
    .document(chatRoomID)
    .collection(chatRoomID)
    .document(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());
```

to:

```
DocumentReference doc = Firestore.instance.document('$firestoreMessageCollection/$chatRoomID/$chatRoomID/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}');
```

I also updated dependencies versions. In my case these are:

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6
firebase_auth: 0.11.1+7
cloud_firestore: 0.12.5+2
firebase_storage: ^3.0.2
firebase_messaging: ^5.0.4
firebase_crashlytics: ^0.0.4+8
```